# ANTLR4 Problems parsing text file with ".*?" parsing expression

Tags: parsing, antlr

I have some trouble parsing this file:

```
TYPE "Frequ"
VERSION : 0.1
// blah blah ...
   INSIDE
      Clk; // Clocks information
      Imp; // Impulse information
   END_INSIDE

END_TYPE
```

The grammar file I used:

```
grammar gr;
type                            :   'TYPE' .*? 'END_TYPE';
```

I "simply" wanted to get all the content between the "TYPE" and "END_TYPE" section.
Shouldn't that be possible somehow?

Error I get from command line:

```
    line 1:0 missing 'TYPE' at 'TYPE "Frequ"\r\nVERSION : 0.1\r\n// blah blah ...\r\
    n   INSIDE\r\n      Clk; // Clocks information\r\n      Imp; // Impulse informat
    ion\r\n   END_INSIDE\r\n\r\nEND_TYPE'
```

Thank's in advance.

-Stirni

Comment: "." is in a parser rule of your grammar. It denotes any token type, not any character. And you don't define any lexer rule for any character. The only lexer rules are for the implicited defined rules for the two string literals.

Comment: Broots Waymb, Llama: Yeah sorry about that.
@kaby76: Thank you. Even without the "." is does not work.
I don't think that I need to define lexer rules for charachters? I just want to get everything between TYPE and END_TYPE

Comment: @Stirni You need to either define a lexer rule with dot, or define a token type for the character set for your input `Any: [0-9,.:;_a-zA-Z]+;`, or additional rules for spaces and non-spaces, or other lexer rules in order to consume the character input and pass the recognized tokens to the parser. Also, I would recommend that you explicitly write all the lexer rules rather than rely on the Antlr4 rules for string literals in parser rules, and print out the token stream independent of calling the parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic issue that you'll run into is how ANTLR tokenizes the input stream and how it resolves conflicting/ambiguous lexer rules.

If two rules match a sting of characters:

- If one string of characters is longer than the other, the longest string of characters wins.
- If they are the same length, the first definition wins.

Ideally, you'd want a Lexer rule that matches everything up to, but excluding the `END_TYPE`

Unfortunately, for Lexer rules, the `~` operator only works on sets, and set members are only single characters, so there's no way to say "everything up to bu excluding `END_TYPE`.  (I tried a predicate, but it included the `END_TYP` part of `END_TYPE` in the longer match.)

with this grammar:

```
grammar gr;

type : 'TYPE' OTHER* 'END_TYPE';

OTHER: .;
```

You can get a parse tree with the `TYPE` and `END_TYPE` tokens, *BUT* every character between  them will be a separate token:

```
[@0,0:3='TYPE',<'TYPE'>,1:0]
[@1,4:4=' ',<OTHER>,1:4]
[@2,5:5='"',<OTHER>,1:5]
[@3,6:6='F',<OTHER>,1:6]
[@4,7:7='r',<OTHER>,1:7]
[@5,8:8='e',<OTHER>,1:8]
[@6,9:9='q',<OTHER>,1:9]
[@7,10:10='u',<OTHER>,1:10]
[@8,11:11='"',<OTHER>,1:11]
[@9,12:12='\n',<OTHER>,1:12]
[@10,13:13='V',<OTHER>,2:0]
[@11,14:14='E',<OTHER>,2:1]
[@12,15:15='R',<OTHER>,2:2]
[@13,16:16='S',<OTHER>,2:3]
[@14,17:17='I',<OTHER>,2:4]
[@15,18:18='O',<OTHER>,2:5]
[@16,19:19='N',<OTHER>,2:6]
[@17,20:20=' ',<OTHER>,2:7]
[@18,21:21=':',<OTHER>,2:8]
[@19,22:22=' ',<OTHER>,2:9]
[@20,23:23='0',<OTHER>,2:10]
[@21,24:24='.',<OTHER>,2:11]
[@22,25:25='1',<OTHER>,2:12]
[@23,26:26='\n',<OTHER>,2:13]
[@24,27:27='/',<OTHER>,3:0]
[@25,28:28='/',<OTHER>,3:1]
[@26,29:29=' ',<OTHER>,3:2]
[@27,30:30='b',<OTHER>,3:3]
[@28,31:31='l',<OTHER>,3:4]
[@29,32:32='a',<OTHER>,3:5]
[@30,33:33='h',<OTHER>,3:6]
[@31,34:34=' ',<OTHER>,3:7]
[@32,35:35='b',<OTHER>,3:8]
[@33,36:36='l',<OTHER>,3:9]
[@34,37:37='a',<OTHER>,3:10]
[@35,38:38='h',<OTHER>,3:11]
[@36,39:39=' ',<OTHER>,3:12]
[@37,40:40='.',<OTHER>,3:13]
[@38,41:41='.',<OTHER>,3:14]
[@39,42:42='.',<OTHER>,3:15]
[@40,43:43='\n',<OTHER>,3:16]
[@41,44:44=' ',<OTHER>,4:0]
[@42,45:45=' ',<OTHER>,4:1]
[@43,46:46=' ',<OTHER>,4:2]
[@44,47:47='I',<OTHER>,4:3]
[@45,48:48='N',<OTHER>,4:4]
[@46,49:49='S',<OTHER>,4:5]
[@47,50:50='I',<OTHER>,4:6]
[@48,51:51='D',<OTHER>,4:7]
[@49,52:52='E',<OTHER>,4:8]
[@50,53:53='\n',<OTHER>,4:9]
[@51,54:54=' ',<OTHER>,5:0]
[@52,55:55=' ',<OTHER>,5:1]
[@53,56:56=' ',<OTHER>,5:2]
[@54,57:57=' ',<OTHER>,5:3]
[@55,58:58=' ',<OTHER>,5:4]
[@56,59:59=' ',<OTHER>,5:5]
[@57,60:60='C',<OTHER>,5:6]
[@58,61:61='l',<OTHER>,5:7]
[@59,62:62='k',<OTHER>,5:8]
[@60,63:63=';',<OTHER>,5:9]
[@61,64:64=' ',<OTHER>,5:10]
[@62,65:65='/',<OTHER>,5:11]
[@63,66:66='/',<OTHER>,5:12]
[@64,67:67=' ',<OTHER>,5:13]
[@65,68:68='C',<OTHER>,5:14]
[@66,69:69='l',<OTHER>,5:15]
[@67,70:70='o',<OTHER>,5:16]
[@68,71:71='c',<OTHER>,5:17]
[@69,72:72='k',<OTHER>,5:18]
[@70,73:73='s',<OTHER>,5:19]
[@71,74:74=' ',<OTHER>,5:20]
[@72,75:75='i',<OTHER>,5:21]
[@73,76:76='n',<OTHER>,5:22]
[@74,77:77='f',<OTHER>,5:23]
[@75,78:78='o',<OTHER>,5:24]
[@76,79:79='r',<OTHER>,5:25]
[@77,80:80='m',<OTHER>,5:26]
[@78,81:81='a',<OTHER>,5:27]
[@79,82:82='t',<OTHER>,5:28]
[@80,83:83='i',<OTHER>,5:29]
[@81,84:84='o',<OTHER>,5:30]
[@82,85:85='n',<OTHER>,5:31]
[@83,86:86='\n',<OTHER>,5:32]
[@84,87:87=' ',<OTHER>,6:0]
[@85,88:88=' ',<OTHER>,6:1]
[@86,89:89=' ',<OTHER>,6:2]
[@87,90:90=' ',<OTHER>,6:3]
[@88,91:91=' ',<OTHER>,6:4]
[@89,92:92=' ',<OTHER>,6:5]
[@90,93:93='I',<OTHER>,6:6]
[@91,94:94='m',<OTHER>,6:7]
[@92,95:95='p',<OTHER>,6:8]
[@93,96:96=';',<OTHER>,6:9]
[@94,97:97=' ',<OTHER>,6:10]
[@95,98:98='/',<OTHER>,6:11]
[@96,99:99='/',<OTHER>,6:12]
[@97,100:100=' ',<OTHER>,6:13]
[@98,101:101='I',<OTHER>,6:14]
[@99,102:102='m',<OTHER>,6:15]
[@100,103:103='p',<OTHER>,6:16]
[@101,104:104='u',<OTHER>,6:17]
[@102,105:105='l',<OTHER>,6:18]
[@103,106:106='s',<OTHER>,6:19]
[@104,107:107='e',<OTHER>,6:20]
[@105,108:108=' ',<OTHER>,6:21]
[@106,109:109='i',<OTHER>,6:22]
[@107,110:110='n',<OTHER>,6:23]
[@108,111:111='f',<OTHER>,6:24]
[@109,112:112='o',<OTHER>,6:25]
[@110,113:113='r',<OTHER>,6:26]
[@111,114:114='m',<OTHER>,6:27]
[@112,115:115='a',<OTHER>,6:28]
[@113,116:116='t',<OTHER>,6:29]
[@114,117:117='i',<OTHER>,6:30]
[@115,118:118='o',<OTHER>,6:31]
[@116,119:119='n',<OTHER>,6:32]
[@117,120:120='\n',<OTHER>,6:33]
[@118,121:121=' ',<OTHER>,7:0]
[@119,122:122=' ',<OTHER>,7:1]
[@120,123:123=' ',<OTHER>,7:2]
[@121,124:124='E',<OTHER>,7:3]
[@122,125:125='N',<OTHER>,7:4]
[@123,126:126='D',<OTHER>,7:5]
[@124,127:127='_',<OTHER>,7:6]
[@125,128:128='I',<OTHER>,7:7]
[@126,129:129='N',<OTHER>,7:8]
[@127,130:130='S',<OTHER>,7:9]
[@128,131:131='I',<OTHER>,7:10]
[@129,132:132='D',<OTHER>,7:11]
[@130,133:133='E',<OTHER>,7:12]
[@131,134:134='\n',<OTHER>,7:13]
[@132,135:135='\n',<OTHER>,8:0]
[@133,136:143='END_TYPE',<'END_TYPE'>,9:0]
[@134,144:143='<EOF>',<EOF>,9:8]
```

This could be quite inefficient, but it's not *QUITE* as bad as it seems; you would not have to concatenate all the other tokens together.  In a Listener, you can do something like:

```
    @Override
    public void exitType(SimpleParser.TypeContext ctx) {
        String text = ts.getText(
           ctx.OTHER(0).getSymbol(), 
           ctx.OTHER(ctx.OTHER().size() - 1).getSymbol()
        );
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

Where `ts` is your TokenStream (you'd need to make that a member variable in you Listener, and populate it).

It would probably be a more performant/flexible to flesh out your tokenization a bit more (even with some very simple lexer rules) to reduce the number of tokens.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `.` inside a parser rule, it means "match any token". Given the grammar:

```
grammar T;

parse : . ;

A : 'aaa';
B : 'bbb';
```

the `.` will only match tokens `A` and `B`.

So you need to define a lexer rule:

```
grammar T;

parse : TYPE;

TYPE
 : 'TYPE' .*? 'END_TYPE'
 ;
```

Inside a lexer rule, `.` matches any character.